# Read Text File from specific places

Tags: c#, split, find, text-files, readfile

I have a question about read a text file, because i dont know if i'm thinking right. I want to read  from specific string to specific character.

My text would look like this:

```
... 
...
CM_ "Hello, how are you?

Rules: Don't smoke!
      - love others

End";
...
CM_ "Why you?";
...// Many CM_
...
```

After Splited should look like that:

```
1. CM_
2. "Hello, how are you?

    Rules: Don't smoke!
      - love others

    End"
3. CM_
4. "Why you?"
... // many CM_
```

I want to read from `"CM_"` till `";"`

My Code i tried so far:

```
StreamReader fin = new StreamReader("text.txt");
string tmp = "";
tmp = fin.ReadToEnd();

if (tmp.StartsWith("CM_ ") && tmp.EndWith(";"))
{
var result = tmp.Split(new[] { '"' }).SelectMany((s, i) =>
                    {
                        if (i % 2 == 1) return new[] { s };
                        return s.Split(new[] { ' ', ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                    }).ToList();
}
foreach (string x in result)
{
   Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    static void PRegex()
    {
        using (StreamReader fin = new StreamReader("text.txt"))
        {
            string tmp = fin.ReadToEnd();

            var matches = Regex.Matches(tmp, "(CM_) ([^;]*);", RegexOptions.Singleline);
            for (int i = 0; i < matches.Count; i++)
                if (matches[i].Groups.Count == 3)
                    Console.WriteLine((2 * i + 1).ToString() + ". " + matches[i].Groups[1].Value + "\r\n" + (2 * (i + 1)).ToString() + ". " + matches[i].Groups[2].Value);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void PLineByLine()
    {
        using (StreamReader fin = new StreamReader("text.txt"))
        {
            int index = 0;
            string line = null;
            string currentCMBlock = null;
            bool endOfBlock = true;
            while ((line = fin.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                bool endOfLine = false;
                while (!endOfLine)
                {
                    if (endOfBlock)
                    {
                        int startIndex = line.IndexOf("CM_ ");
                        if (startIndex == -1)
                        {
                            endOfLine = true;
                            continue;
                        }
                        line = line.Substring(startIndex + 4, line.Length - startIndex - 4);
                        endOfBlock = false;
                    }

                    if (!endOfBlock)
                    {
                        int startIndex = line.IndexOf(";");
                        if (startIndex == -1)
                        {
                            currentCMBlock += line + "\r\n";
                            endOfLine = true;
                            continue;
                        }
                        currentCMBlock += line.Substring(0, startIndex);
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentCMBlock))
                            Console.WriteLine((++index) + ". CM_\r\n" + (++index) + ". " + currentCMBlock);
                        currentCMBlock = null;
                        line = line.Substring(startIndex + 1, line.Length - startIndex - 1);
                        endOfBlock = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: good one, but if i have many CM_ like another `CM_ "Why";` and want to edit all of them? how could you change your if statment?

Comment: thank you very much, it works great. Is there any solution with readline? I have tried for hours but can't get it work

Comment: If you have to read one line at a time (and aren't allowed to just accumulate them in a string, which would defeat the purpose of reading line by line) it's a bit more complicated. I added such a solution too.

Comment: 'Environment.NewLine' is safer than "\r\n".

Answer (score 0):

You are reading the whole file into tmp.  So, if there is any text before "CM_" then your conditional statement won't be entered.

Instead, try reading line by line with fin.ReadLine in a loop over all lines.

Comment: so i would do `while ((tmp = fin.ReadLine()) != null)
            { ...}` but still dont know  how further

Answer (score 0):

Read the whole file:

```
string FileToRead = File.ReadAllText("Path");

string GetContent(string StartAt, string EndAt, bool LastIndex)
{
string ReturnVal;

if(LastIndex)
{
ReturnVal = FileToRead.Remove(FileToRead.IndexOf(StartAt), FileToRead.IndexOf(EndAt));
Return ReturnVal;
}
else
{ 
ReturnVal = FileToRead.Remove(FileToRead.LastIndex(StartAt), FileToRead.LastIndex(EndAt));
Return ReturnVal;
}
}
```

-Hope I didn't do anything wrong here. (Free mind typing)

You read the file, and we remove all the content, infront of the first index. and all after it.
You can set it if will return the FIRST result found. or the last.

NOTE: I think it would be better to use a StringReader. (If I don't remember wrong...)
If you are to think about the memory usage of your application.

Answer (score 0):

I tried something else, don't know if this is good. It still read the first Line, dont know that i did wrong here

my Code:

```
        while ((tmp = fin.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (tmp.StartsWith("CM_ "))
            {

                //string[] tmpList = tmp.Split(new Char[] { ' ', ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                var result = tmp.Split(new[] { '"' }).SelectMany((s, i) =>
                {
                    if (i % 2 == 1) return new[] { s };
                    return s.Split(new[] { ' ', ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                }).ToList();

                if (tmp.EndsWith(";")) break;

                fin.ReadLine();

                if (tmp.EndsWith(";"))
                {
                    result.ToList();
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    result.ToList();
                    fin.ReadLine();
                }

                foreach (string x in result)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(x);
                }
            }
```

Comment: It's usually better to edit your question than post additional information in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look into using Regular Expressions. It may be just what you need and much more flexible than Split().